# how to create gradient in svg

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to create a gradient in a svg but i do not succeed in it. 
This is my code:

```
<svg class="defs-only" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <symbol id="bottomwave">    
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
    <g>
    <path fill="#009de1" d="M 27 4.125C 21 6.125 14 11 0 11L 0 13.9962L 54 14L 54 0C 40 0 33 2.125 27 4.125Z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

combined with this:

```
<svg class="homepage-wave-bottom" style="width: 100%; height: 250px" fill="url(#gradient)">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
        <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="#102b72"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#009de1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#bottomwave"/>

</svg>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jotect8j/1/

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by defining the gradient within the "bottomwave" svg, which is what is using the gradient fill, and setting the path fill to that gradient:

```html
<svg class="defs-only" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
        <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="#102b72"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#009de1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <symbol id="bottomwave" fill="url(#gradient)">    
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
    <g>
    <path fill="url(#gradient)" d="M 27 4.125C 21 6.125 14 11 0 11L 0 13.9962L 54 14L 54 0C 40 0 33 2.125 27 4.125Z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
</symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="homepage-wave-bottom" style="width: 100%; height: 250px">
  <use xlink:href="#bottomwave"/>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fill overwrites the gradient. See below:

```
 <path fill="#009de1" d="M 27 4.125C 21 6.125 14 11 0 11L 0 13.9962L 54 14L 54 0C 40 0 33 2.125 27 4.125Z"></path>
```

So avoiding it should do the trick:

```
 <path d="M 27 4.125C 21 6.125 14 11 0 11L 0 13.9962L 54 14L 54 0C 40 0 33 2.125 27 4.125Z"></path>
```